# How to find the best fit for given input data?

Tags: fitting, interpolation

I have the following data:

```
top = 
  {{0., 59.5}, {0.1, 30.7}, {0.2, 21.1}, {0.3, -7.73}, {0.4, -17.3}, {1., -36.6}, 
   {5., -75.}, {8., -104.}, {10., -123.}, {15., -94.2}, {20., -65.4}, {35., -36.6}, 
   {65., -7.73}, {100., 1.87}}
```

Using `ListPlot` I see that there is some order in the data. I get a feeling that some kind of smooth function could be fitted to it. But I have huge problems when I am trying to do that.

I tried to use `Interpolation[top]` but I wasn't really satisfied. Then I tried `InterpolatingPolynomial[top, x]` which turned out to be even worse. Then I tried to use `Fit` for different polynomial orders but again nothing seemed useful.

And I am sure I am not the first one with this problem, so my question is: what can one do in that case?

I was thinking also thinking about making a linear interpolation between points, but I have to admit that I would rather see something smoother. So is there a way I can make things smoother? :/

Maybe I should consider three or more parts and than combine them together?

Please note that the data I provided is almost random. Almost means that the next file I will import may not have an extreme value at (10.0, -132.0) but maybe at (9.0, -125.0). But the shape shall be more or less the same. Just saying this in the case it might change anything.

Comment: Is this good enough? `f = Interpolation[top, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline"]` and `Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 100}]`

Comment: One thing you could try is filtering your data  and try a fit or an interpolation on the filtered result. Another approach would be to come up with some kind of more complex model and try to fit that with NonLinearModelFit

Comment: `f[t_] = Normal[NonlinearModelFit[top, a + b E^(-c t) - d t E^(-e t), {a, b, c, d, e}, t]]` is more beautiful, but it doesn't evaluate to the exact values.

Comment: @Coolwater : The first idea is quite fine, but I would like to check the NonLinearModel too. Yet I can't see where the problem is but this is what mathematica says (check the link): http://www4.slikomat.com/13/0715/4xv-Captur.png

Comment: Quite likely, the theory behind where your data came from might provide a model you can use.

Comment: Version 10.2 will contain FindFormula which might do the job. A non-Mathematica alternative would be the semi-free Eureqa.

Comment: @skrat the problem with the code in your link seems to be that almost all symbols you used as parameters for your models already have values ( they're black, not blue).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries - on my Mac with v10.2, `FindFormula[top, t]` just returns the constant `-32.4564` (the `Mean` of the f[t] values). This new function is marked `[[EXPERIMENTAL]]` in the documentation and for this problem does not contribute anything. Perhaps the option `TargetFunctions` could be tuned for a decent fit but by then you would almost have guessed a model for use with `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: That's  disappointing. I'm still waiting to get 10.2 so I can't test it myself.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries :Yes, true! Silly me. -.-   One more thing: I defined a function g = 0.5 - Interpolation[top, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline"] and now if I write g[any_value_from_domain] I get no result. It's like mathematica doesn't want to recognize g as a function. I'm losing hair here -.-

Comment: The sum of some number and a pure function does not equal a pure function as a whole. You should define g as g=(0.5+Interpolation[...][#])&.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: With only 14 data points and no repeats for any predictor value you're never going to be totally confident about a fit (especially if there is much of any departure from a straight line).  Knowing how the data is generated and if there might be some expected form for the response (both in mean and variance about the mean value) would certainly greatly supplement the data.  This topic would probably be best addressed at Cross Validated (http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @bob On 10.2 now as well. You got the zeroth order fit. Playing a bit with SpecificityGoal yields other results although not really fantastic.